# continuous record/recognize audio with pocketsphinx/ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx, continuous

as the title already says, I want to continuous record raw audio through my microphone.
So the idea was running a simple C program in the background as service that would create chunks of audio and send those files through the sphinx speech recognition.

After that I can do some processing with the recognized words.

The problem is the (continuous) recognition. I can't just record audio chunks containing 10 seconds what i've said, because maybe chunk[33] -> chunk[34] belong together and then sphinx would output something like:

```
recognized chunk[33] -> ["enable light"]
recognized chunk[34] -> ["5 with 50 percent"]
```

Another approach would be to continuous record audio but then I can't process big audio files with sphinx.

I'm using the basic [example](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx/) from pocketsphinx:

```
#include <pocketsphinx.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
ps_decoder_t *ps;
cmd_ln_t *config;
FILE *fh;
char const *hyp, *uttid;
int16 buf[512];
int rv;
int32 score;

config = cmd_ln_init(NULL, ps_args(), TRUE,
             "-hmm", MODELDIR "/en-us/en-us",
             "-lm", MODELDIR "/en-us/en-us.lm.bin",
             "-dict", MODELDIR "/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict",
             NULL);
if (config == NULL) {
fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create config object, see log for details\n");
return -1;
}

ps = ps_init(config);
if (ps == NULL) {
fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create recognizer, see log for details\n");
return -1;
}

fh = fopen("audiochunk_33.raw", "rb");
if (fh == NULL) {
fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open input file goforward.raw\n");
return -1;
}

rv = ps_start_utt(ps);

while (!feof(fh)) {
size_t nsamp;
nsamp = fread(buf, 2, 512, fh);
rv = ps_process_raw(ps, buf, nsamp, FALSE, FALSE);
}

rv = ps_end_utt(ps);
hyp = ps_get_hyp(ps, &score);
printf("Recognized: %s\n", hyp);

fclose(fh);
ps_free(ps);
cmd_ln_free_r(config);

return 0;
```

}

And [here](https://batchloaf.wordpress.com/2017/02/10/a-simple-way-to-read-and-write-audio-and-video-files-in-c-using-ffmpeg/) is a basic example using ffmpeg to create a simple audio file/chunk:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>

#define N 44100

void main()
{
// Create audio buffer
int16_t buf[N] = {0}; // buffer
int n;                // buffer index
double Fs = 44100.0;  // sampling frequency

// Generate 1 second of audio data - it's just a 1 kHz sine wave
for (n=0 ; n<N ; ++n) buf[n] = 16383.0 * sin(n*1000.0*2.0*M_PI/Fs);

// Pipe the audio data to ffmpeg, which writes it to a wav file
FILE *pipeout;
pipeout = popen("ffmpeg -y -f s16le -ar 44100 -ac 1 -i - beep.wav", "w");
fwrite(buf, 2, N, pipeout);
pclose(pipeout);
}
```

BR
Michael

Comment: You need to check https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/blob/master/src/programs/continuous.c, the source of pocketsphinx_continuous to see how to decode continuous stream properly. ffmpeg is irrelevant here.